# Oracle client server connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Can anyone help me in the regard, that if we install Oracle client on a 32 bit Windows operating system, and trying  to connect to a oracle server installed on 64 bit windows operating system?

Will it connect or not because i am not able to

Comment: Need more details. Errors? Current configuration? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to connect.

There is no issue on this.

Comment: I am connecting through TNS, but it's not able to connect.

Comment: Did you get your service name or service ID correct? It is common for Oracle DBMS to be on a 64 bit machine having gigabytes of RAM for disposal, however, it doesn't mean the client needs to be a 64 bit machine, or even match up to the operating system of the server.